# Graph a colored cube

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I work on a statistical code that generates a variety of graphs with Matlab.  The graph types range from simple pie and bar charts to 3D histogram lattices.

Now we would like a nice GUI to go with the software.  We have a prototype Matlab GUI, but Matlab's GUI has a number of issues, so we'd like to move to a more robust GUI.  My best option seems to be PySide + matplotlib, but so far I haven't found an way to plot the 3D lattice.  The matlab code uses contourslice.  There doesn't seem to be a similar call in matplotlib.  So, can anyone help me figure out how I might get a graph like this with matplotlib?  So far my only idea is to graph 6 surfaces to make a cube.

Actually, recommendations for other GUI/Graph library combinations are also welcome.  The bases stat code is C++, so Python is just one of many options.  Judging from some of the answers I've seen on StackOverflow, matplotlib may be unacceptably slow in 3D.  Perhaps R would be better?

[image: A colored 3D cube made with contourslice]

Here's the matlab code:

```
clf
xlo = -1.800000e+01; 
xhi = 1.000000e+01; 
ylo = 1.000000e+01; 
yhi = 3.000000e+01; 
zlo = -1.000000e+03; 
zhi = 1.000000e+03; 
X=zeros(16,16,16);
Y=zeros(16,16,16);
Z=zeros(16,16,16);
V=zeros(16,16,16);
% fill in X, Y, Z, and V  huge amount of text
xt = [-1.800000e+01:2.800000e-01:1.000000e+01];
yt = [1.000000e+01:2.000000e-01:3.000000e+01];
zt = [-1.000000e+03:2.000000e+01:1.000000e+03];
isoval = -1.428280e+01;
h = patch(isosurface(X,Y,Z,V,isoval),... 
'FaceColor', 'blue', ... 
'EdgeColor', 'none', ... 
'AmbientStrength', 0.2, ... 
'SpecularStrength', 0.7, ... 
'DiffuseStrength', 0.4);
isonormals(X,Y,Z,V,h);
patch(isocaps(X,Y,Z,V,isoval), ...
'FaceColor', 'interp', ... 
'EdgeColor', 'none'); 
axis([xlo xhi ylo yhi zlo zhi])
daspect([2.800000e+01,2.000000e+01,2.000000e+03])
set(gca,'linewidth',2)
set(gca,'fontweight','bold')
set(gca,'fontsize',12)
grid on
box on
colormap('default'); colorbar

view(3) 
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer')
lighting phong
cin = 'n';
if (cin == 'y')
xin = questdlg('Axis to slide through ?', 'Axis', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X');
xin = lower(xin);
for i = 1 : 101
if gcf ~= plotFigure
return
end
if (xin == 'y')
h = contourslice(X,Y,Z,V,xt(i),[],[],101);
elseif (xin == 'x')
h = contourslice(X,Y,Z,V,[],yt(i),[],101);
elseif (xin == 'z')
h = contourslice(X,Y,Z,V,[],[],zt(i),101);
end
axis([-1.8000e+01  1.0000e+01  1.0000e+01  3.0000e+01 -1.0000e+03  1.0000e+03 -8.6774e+01  4.2066e+02])
set(gca,'linewidth',2)
set(gca,'fontweight','bold')
set(gca,'fontsize',12)
grid on
box on
view(3)
set(h, 'Linewidth', 10)
colorbar
pause(0.3)
if (i < 101)
clf
end
end
end
```

Comment: Why exactly is matlab not working for you?

Comment: Well, continuing with matlab is a possibility.  I need to experiment with the matlab compiler to see if it would allow me to distribute without requiring the users to have matlab licenses.
My main complaint is that it isn't very dynamic, I can't expand a table on the fly, for example.  It's also slow and kinda flaky.

Comment: It is possible to distribute a compiled application to end users without them needing a matlab licenses. They only need to install the MCR(Matlab Runtime Compiler) which is freely available. As for speed, python is certainly not any faster in most settings.

Comment: also this nice [package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32697-making-matlab-swing) integrates Java Swing functionality into Matlab GUIs.

Comment: The question isn't so much if the matlab compiler works for some cases, it's if it works for my case. :)  I thought it wouldn't due to some oddities of how the statistical package interacts with matlab, but I think I may know how to work around those.
Thanks for the Swing link as well.  More tools to try out...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [`mayavi`](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html)
If you are using Windows, it comes by default with [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/).